# Any Update on Colin's ALM Checkin Policies for VS 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, checkin, tfs-code-review

I am searching Colin's ALM Checkin Policies For VS 2022, but unable to do it, if you guys have a link please let me know.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: `I'm no longer making changes for any version of this policy except VS 2017.` https://github.com/colindembovsky/ColinsALMCornerCheckinPolicies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently this repository is no longer being updated by the author:

> I'm no longer making changes for any version of this policy except VS 2017.

**Source:** github.com/colindembovsky/ColinsALMCornerCheckinPolicies

Another user has added support for the 2019 and 2022 versions and there is a pull request open to update the original one.

**Here is the link to the repository:**

https://github.com/vbtrek/ColinsALMCornerCheckinPolicies

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nemanja228/ColinsALMCornerCheckinPolicies/releases/download/vs2022/ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesInstaller.vsix

> Use this File Directly TO Install VS 2022 Colin's ALM Checkin Policy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).